# Difference NVME 1.1 and 1.3

Tags: nvme

I want to get an M.2 SSD for my Dell G3 3579 laptop. From the [specification PDF](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/g-series-15-3579-laptop_users-guide_en-us.pdf) I found that it supports M.2 SSD. Here is a screenshot from the PDF file,

[image]

But in other part of the specification PDF it says NVME 1.1. Here is another screenshot,
[image]

This concerns me because I want to [Samsung 970 EVO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BN4NJ2J) and it says NVME 1.3 in its specification.

I am wondering Samsung 970 EVO will get running at full capacity? or I am connecting NVME 1.3 device on a socket that is expecting 1.1 device. I am not sure if I am conflating two different things.

Comment: The second screenshot applies to Optane devices. 970 EVO is not an Optane disk, it's a regular NVMe SSD. Take a look at number of PCIe lanes: for Optane only 2 lanes are used despite 4 being available.

Comment: oh okay. Just to reiterate - the NVMe 1.1 is for Optane, therefore it does not affect Samsung  970 EVO?

Comment: Strictly speaking, we don't know. The document specifies that Optane disks will use NVMe 1.1, but it doesn't clarify which version of spec is implemented. Looks like it's a 2018 model, so it should support at least 1.3a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the one hand the Dell G3 3579 supports "PCIe 3x4 NVMe".
On the other hand the
[Samsung 970 EVO specifications](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/970evo/)
says "INTERFACE - PCIe Gen 3.0 x4, NVMe 1.3".

The two devices should then work together, and as both support 4 data-lanes,
the Samsung 970 EVO should run at full capacity.

Although by the specifications there is no reason for the  Samsung 970 EVO
not to work in the Dell G3 3579, it is better to find real-world testimonies
for it as further proof.

The same question was asked in the post
 [NVMe vs SATA for M.2 SSD? Samsung 970 EVO Dell G3 5379 NVMe SSD Support?](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/128648-nvme-vs-sata-m-2-ssd-samsung-970-evo.html).
The poster received a positive answer, then later reported that the SSD worked
well in his computer in a very satisfactory way.

I also found a Polish computer model
[BIAŁY DELL G3 3579 i5-8300H 16GB EVO970+1TB W10](https://archiwum.allegro.pl/oferta/bialy-dell-g3-3579-i5-8300h-16gb-evo970-1tb-w10-i7686292598.html).
Although I can't read the text, it's clear enough that this computer model
is sold with exactly the same setup as the one you are thinking of.

The answer is then that the specifications of the Intel Optane memory
do not relate to the Samsung 970 EVO,
or more precisely that the motherboard of the Dell supports both protocols.

Comment: You should answer the author’s one and only question, “ I am wondering Samsung 970 EVO will get running at full capacity?”, your answer does not seem to address that question.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for your extensive research!